# Common Argument Pass in Method

Tags: java, hibernate, methods

I have a method called makePersistent in my DAO class. 
Currntly we have this method in all dao classes and what i need to do is convert this method to common format. So is there any way to do it?

**Method in UserDao Class**

```
public void makePersistent(User model) throws InfrastructureException {
        try {
            getSession().saveOrUpdate(model);
            getSession().flush();
            getSession().clear();
        } catch (org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException ex) {
            throw new InfrastructureException(Labels.getString("com.tran.msg.objectDeletedOrUpdated"));
        } catch (HibernateException ex) {
            throw new InfrastructureException(ex);
        }
    }
```

**Method in HolidayDao Class**

```
public void makePersistent(Holiday model) throws InfrastructureException {
        try {
            getSession().saveOrUpdate(model);
            getSession().flush();
            getSession().clear();
        } catch (org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException ex) {
            throw new InfrastructureException(Labels.getString("com.tran.msg.objectDeletedOrUpdated"));
        } catch (HibernateException ex) {
            throw new InfrastructureException(ex);
        }
    }
```

Please help me to get rid of this redundant coding. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Just use Object the hibernate will persist it.


public void makePersistent(Object model) throws InfrastructureException {
         try {
            getSession().saveOrUpdate(model);
            getSession().flush();
            getSession().clear();
        } catch (org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException ex) {
            throw new InfrastructureException(Labels.getString("com.tran.msg.objectDeletedOrUpdaed"));
        } catch (HibernateException ex) {
            throw new InfrastructureException(ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Perfect thats what i looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Create a superclass for your DAOs with a type parameter and make your DAO classes extend that superclass with the appropriate type argument. For example:

```
public class BaseDao<T> {

    public void makePersistent(T model) throws InfrastructureException {
        try {
            getSession().saveOrUpdate(model);
            getSession().flush();
            getSession().clear();
        } catch (org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException ex) {
            throw new InfrastructureException(Labels.getString("com.tran.msg.objectDeletedOrUpdated"));
        } catch (HibernateException ex) {
            throw new InfrastructureException(ex);
        }
    }
}

public class UserDao extends BaseDao<User> {
    // ...
}

public class HolidayDao extends BaseDao<Holiday> {
    // ...
}
```

`UserDao` and `HolidayDao` inherit the `makePersistent` method from `BaseDao`, so you don't have to implement it again in every DAO class.